# JButton Transparency on an BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jbutton, bufferedimage

I have a Problem:

I'm rendering a BufferedImage in a JFrame. Then i add a JButton to the same frame.
when i try to make the button transparent, the button becomes transparent, but disregarding its actual position, its always transparent like it is stuck in the top left corner of the frame.
I testet some different methods to make the button transparent, always with the same result.

any ideas?

thanks

```
public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

public TestPanel(){
    JButton foo = new JButton("test");
    foo.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    foo.setBounds(20, 100, 300, 50);
    this.add(foo);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(ImageFactory.getImg(), 0, 0, null); //get a BufferedImage
    g2.dispose();
}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see several problems, even if I'm not sure on which of them cause your problem.I try to list them in order:

1. Your `TestPanel` doesn't specify a `LayoutManager` (I hope you are specifying it somewhere else in your code).
2. You are extending a `JPanel` without call super paintComponent method (don't use paint). You should do this before anything else in your paintComponent method:

   ```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g); 
   }
   ```
3. remove the dispose method call. You must not destroy your graphic object.

EDIT:

1. this is a problem:

   ```
   foo.setBounds(20, 100, 300, 50);
   ```

   you are trying to explicitly set the bounds of your JButton. You shouldn't do that. If you are using a LayoutManager it probably ignore this directive. If you are using a null layout this could be a problem too.

Comment: I think that layout problem is related to the LayoutManager issue. Are you specifying a LayoutManager? If yes which one, where and how? post the relative code.

Comment: @Heisenbug please to change paint() method (and both) to the paintComponent() :-) +1

Comment: it's not "don't need to destroy", it's "must not destroy" :)

Comment: Ok, fixed. The Problem was indeed the null Layout. now it works perfectly with opaque set to false and the transparent background color. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Several problems

- it's wrong to override paint, instead override paintComponent
- the button has a fully transparent background but returns true for opaque, thus fooling the paint mechanism
- it's wrong to dispose the Graphics passed in as parameter

working code (Edit: accidentally removed the transparent color-setting line, fixed)

```
public TestPanel(){
    JButton foo = new JButton("test");
    foo.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    foo.setOpaque(false);
    foo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    this.add(foo);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(ImageFactory.getImg(), 0, 0, null); //get a BufferedImage
   //   g2.dispose();
}
```

As others already noted: LayoutManagers are a *must* in Swing/AWT - not using them makes the ui code brittle and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

`setBound()` will work only if you have set your layout to null. Your code does not say anything like that.
Now, the default layout manager of `JPanel` is [`FlowLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html). By default, this layout manager will arrange your components from left to right then top to bottom.

Now, to make your code work as expected. Add this line inside your constructor: `setLayout(null)`.
But remember, setting the layout to null is a very poor practice.
Also, the points Heisenbug has mentioned are very worthy. Try to follow them.

Comment: -1 *"..will work only if you have set your layout to null."*  ..at which point everything *else* will begin to fail.  **Use layouts.**

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for the point. I wanted to mean "setBound() will be EFFECTIVE if layout is null". Agreed now? :)

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that it is a bad idea  to set the layout to null.  Agreed now?

Comment: @Andrew: Oh. I misunderstood your first comment. I also mentioned in my answer that this is a very bad idea: "But remember, setting the layout to null is a very poor practice". I just wanted to make clear why the code was not working as expected. Even I recommended Heisenbug's solution which was accepted later.